# landscape environment and margins on the same side

Tags: margins, geometry, landscape, pdflscape, lscape

I have a long table (it is just text in the MWE) in a landscape environment with the `pdflscape` package. I want to set the top margin for all the pages in landscape mode.
So I import the `geometry` package. Since the page is rotated, I use `\newgeometry{left=5cm}` to set the top margin (notice "left" instead of "top").
The problem is that for even pages the bottom margin is set, and for odd pages the top margin is set. I want to set all the top margins and only the top margins, both for even and for odd pages.

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image: bottom and top margins]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Test}
    \lipsum

    \chapter{Test 2}

    \newgeometry{left=10cm}
    \begin{landscape}
        \lipsum
        \lipsum
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\newgeometry{left=10cm,asymmetric}`. But note that the width of the page header will be changed too.

Comment: It works, thanks. Yes that is what I needed, to also change the header width